# How to pass arguments to executeable in windows command line program from php?

Tags: php, windows, web, scripting, exec

I have a program which I can execute from the command line in windows7, and pass in some arguments. The program does some calculations, and writes to a text file, then closes. No output goes to the command line.

What I need to do is execute this program via a php web-page.
I have been reading the PHP manual, and I still can't seem to get the program to run properly.

This snippet executes the EXE. Evidently, my problem is getting the arguments to be seen by the EXE.

```
<?php 
$du = 'Unity.exe';
echo exec($du);
echo $command;
?>
```

Here, where I try to pass in arguments, The EXE never runs, and the arguments are lost or something.

```
<?php 
//Date (no year), Time(am | pm), Name, Duration, Experiment type.
//05/05 10:00,.5,User
$du = 'C:\Apache24\old\Unity.exe';
$command = $du . ' 05/06, 1:00 AM, .5, Joh';
echo exec($command);
echo $command;
?>
```

I am not sure what to do. exec($command, $return_var); always comes back as 1, and no text is written to the text file.

UPDATE:

How should I pass arguments to the exe via php?
This line:
$command = $du . ' 05/06, 1:00 AM, .5, Joh';

Clearly isn't working as i expected.

Comment: Not good look with this aproach, you could find a better way using a Linux platform ;)

Comment: I am a Linux user. My boss isnt. if it were up to me, I would rewrite this in php, and run it from my Linux server, using a database. But we arent doing that, and I cant rewrite it by Monday. So I need this to work.

Comment: Maybe I can make it run in Linux, under wine. I mean, everything about this project is ridiculous. I might as well go all out.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible if you use [`popen()`](http://php.net/manual/function.popen.php) it's a like `fopen()` but you work with command line programs. So you can read the output with `fread()` or `fgets()`.

That 1 you get is the exit code or the return value of the main function which you may know from c/c++. In Linux you can read it with `echo $#` if I remember correctly and in Windows it is `echo %errorlevel%`.

Answer (score 1):

here is a list of tests i ran

> test.php

```
<?php
echo exec('echo "abc "');
echo "<br>";
echo exec('copy "test.php" "test2.php"');
echo "<br>";
echo exec('test.bat "hello this is a test"');
echo "<br>";
echo exec('test2.bat hello this is a test');
?>
```

**test.bat**

```
echo %1
```

**test2.bat**

```
@echo off
echo %1 - %2 - %3 - %4 - %5
```

**output**

```
"abc "
1 file(s) copied.
"hello this is a test"
hello - this - is - a - test
```

so, try using a bat file in the same folder as the php file for bypassing the arguments, 
like,

**test.php**

echo exec('test.bat 05/06 1:00AM .5 Joh');

**test.bat**

```
Unity.exe %1 %2 %3 %4
```

(and please do note that in most cases 'space' is used to separate the arguments)